# Find $a$ such that $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}(\sqrt3 \tan x)^\frac{(a+1)\tan (3x)}{\sin x} = e^\frac{-8\sqrt3}{3}$

Tags: limits, analysis, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

> What is the value of $a$ such that:
>   $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\bigg(\sqrt3 \tan x\bigg)^\frac{(a+1)\tan (3x)}{\sin x} = e^\frac{-8\sqrt3}{3}$$

After using $\lim_{x\to 0}(1 + x)^\frac{1}{x}$, i have

$$e ^{\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt3 \tan x - 1}{\sin x}\bigg) (a+1)\tan (3x)} = e^\frac{-8\sqrt3}{3}$$

Any hints for what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find $a$ such that:

$$(a+1)\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt3 \tan x - 1}{\sin x}\bigg)\tan 3x = \frac{-8\sqrt3}{3}$$

or

$$2(a+1)\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}} (\sqrt3 \tan x - 1) \tan 3x= \frac{-8\sqrt3}{3}$$

Now, let's evaluate the limit:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}} (\sqrt3 \tan x - 1) \tan 3x &= \lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sqrt3 \sin x - \cos x}{\cos x}\cdot \frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x}\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{\cos 3x}\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{\cos 3x}\\
&= \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{\cos x(1-2\sin x)(1+2\sin x)}\\
&= \frac{4}{3}\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{4 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{x}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{x}{2}\right)}\\
&= \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{x}{2}\right)}\\
&= -\frac{4}{3\sqrt{3}}\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{x-\frac{\pi}{6}}\cdot \frac{\frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{x}{2}}{ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{x}{2}\right)}\\
&= -\frac{4}{3\sqrt{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

The final answer is $a=2$.

Comment: How, on taking logarithms, do you get from $\sqrt3\tan x$ to $\sqrt3\tan x-1$?

Comment: @BarryCipra, I continued from OP's work. He used $\lim\limits_{f(x)\to 0} (1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=e$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{3}\tan x-1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

If $$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f(x))^{g(x)} \rightarrow 1^{\infty}$$
then
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x \rightarrow a} [g(x)(f(x)-1)].$$
So here
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi/6}[\frac{(a+1)\tan 3x}{\sin x}] [\sqrt{3} \tan x-1]]$$
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi/6}[\frac{(a+1)}{\sin x}]\frac{ [\sqrt{3} \tan x-1]}{\cot 3x}]$$
Using L-Hospital's Rulr
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi/6} \frac{ [\sqrt{3} \tan x-1]}{\cot 3x}= \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi/6} \frac{\sqrt{3} \sec^2 a}{-3\csc^2 3x}=-\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$
Then $$L=e^{-\frac{8(a+1)}{\sqrt{3}}}
=e^{-\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{3}} \implies a=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

If L'Hopital is allowed, the value of $a$ can be derived in relatively straightforward manner:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\left(\sqrt3\tan x \right)^{(a+1)\tan3x/\sin x}=e^{-8\sqrt3/3}
&\implies\lim_{x\to\pi/6}{(a+1)\tan3x\over\sin x}\ln(\sqrt3\tan x)={-8\sqrt3\over3}\\
&\implies a+1={-8\sqrt3\over3}\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\left({\sin x\over\sin3x}{\cos3x\over\ln(\sqrt3\tan x)} \right)\\
&\implies a+1={-8\sqrt3\over3}\cdot{1/2\over1}\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\left(\cos3x\over\ln(\sqrt3\tan x)\right)\\
&\implies a+1={-4\sqrt3\over3}\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\left(-3\sin3x\over\sec^2x/\tan x \right)\\
&\implies a+1=4\sqrt3\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\left(\sin x\cos x\sin3x \right)\\
&\implies a+1=4\sqrt3\cdot{1\over2}\cdot{\sqrt3\over2}\cdot1=3\\
&\implies a=2
\end{align}$$

The key step is to check that $\lim_{x\to\pi6}\cos3x=\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\ln(\sqrt3\tan x)=0$, so that L'Hopital's Rule can be applied. If L'Hopital is not allowed (as the OP's tag indicates), $\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\cos3x/\ln(\sqrt3\tan x)$ can still be evaluated using the definition of the derivative:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}{\cos3x\over\ln(\sqrt3\tan x)}={\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\pi/6}{\cos3x-\cos(\pi/2)\over x-\pi/6}}\over\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\pi/6}{\ln(\sqrt3\tan x)-\ln(\sqrt3\tan(\pi/6)\over x-\pi/6}}}={-3\sin(\pi/2)\over\sec^2(\pi/6)/\tan(\pi/6)}$$